# finding local maximum and range of function

Tags: calculus

Consider the function $f(x)= \frac{ln x}{x}$, $0 < x < e^2$.

(a)   (i) Solve the equation $f'(x) = 0$

- here I differenciated and I got $f'(x)= \frac{\frac{x}{ln x}-ln x}{x^2}$ and when I equated this to zero, I got $x=0$

  (ii) Hence show the graph of $f$ has a local maximum.

  (iii) Write down the range of the function $f$.

(b) Show that there is a point of inflexion on the graph and determine its coordinates.

(c) Sketch the graph of $y=f(x)$, indicating clearly the asymptote, x-intercept and the local maximum.

(d)Now consider the functions $g(x)=\frac{ln|x|}{x}$ and $h(x)=\frac{ln|x|}{|x|}$, where $0<|x|>e^2$.

```
(i) Sketch the graph of $y=g(x)$
(ii) Write down the range of $g$
(iii) Find the values of x such that $h(x) > g(x)$.
```

I'm not quite sure how to approach after the first derivative.

Comment: When you differentiate you should get $1-\ln x$ on top.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

As André Nicolas commented, the first derivative is wrong. If $$f(x)=\frac{\log(x)}{x}$$ $$f'(x)=\frac{1-\log (x)}{x^2}$$ $$f''(x)=\frac{2 \log (x)-3}{x^3}$$ So, $f'(x)=0$ when $x=e$ and for this value $f''(x)=-\frac{1}{e^3} \lt 0$; so there is a maximum for $x=e$ corresponding to $f(e)=\frac{1}{e}$.

The second derivative cancels if $2 \log (x)-3=0$ which corresponds to $x=e^{3/2}$ which is in the considered range.

I am sure that you can take from here.